# javascript convert timestamp to 2 digit style of hours/minutes

Tags: javascript

```
new Date(timestamp).getHours();
new Date(timestamp).getMinutes();
```

I have a timestamp, i convert it to h/m, ex.**00:00**

how can I convert it to the format with 2 digit style, what I have now is **0:0**

Comment: If you don't like reinventing wheels, consider [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to pad your digits.

Try this:

```
var h = new Date(timestamp).getHours();
var m = new Date(timestamp).getMinutes();

h = (h<10) ? '0' + h : h;
m = (m<10) ? '0' + m : m;

var output = h + ':' + m;
```

Or place the padding in a function:

```
function pad(val){
     return (val<10) ? '0' + val : val;
}
```

And use that like this:

```
var h = new Date(timestamp).getHours();
var m = new Date(timestamp).getMinutes();
var output = pad(h) + ':' + pad(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works without creating a function, or having too many lines of code and works with locale is to use `toTimeString()`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString

```
let ts = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:01').toTimeString();
console.log(ts);
// output: 23:15:01 GMT+0200 (CEST)

let hhmm = ts.toTimeString().slice(3, 9);
console.log(hhmm);
// output: 15:01
```

Here is your one-liner:

```
new Date(timestamp).toTimeString().slice(3, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
var date    = new Date(timestamp),
    hours   = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes();

var output  = ("0" + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to have little helper around for these tasks. Like this function - `padZero()`

```
var h = padZero(new Date(timestamp).getHours() );
var m = padZero(new Date(timestamp).getMinutes() );

function padZero(n) {
  if (n < 10) return '0' + n;
  return n;
}
```